# Shall I use "fill in" or "fill out"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, phrasal-verbs

I'm preparing a mind map on a particular topic in which all the information is missing  and have to be found. As an instruction, shall I write: "fill in the mind map" or "Fill out the mind map?". Thanks for your help.

Comment: Besides, concerning just questions or answers with missing words in them, which is correct: "Fill in" or "Fill out" the questions/answers below?

Comment: Don't know a lot about mind maps, but we generally *fill out* forms (completing an entire form) but *fill in* blank spaces (within a form).

Answer (score 1):

You could use either

> **Fill out** the mind map

relating to the form in general, or

> **Fill in**, *the missing gaps in,* the mind map

the spaces *in-between*.